# Jquery Select2 Filtering options based on a list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using jquery-select2 plugin and been in this problem because when i save this form, it add the last value in the list even if i haven't selected it.

```
$("#id_structure").change(function(){
var hierarchy_id = $("#id_structure").val();
$.post("/org/branches/",
{
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}','hierarchy_id':hierarchy_id
},function(data)
{
    $('#id_branches').find('option').remove();
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(obj, function(i)
    {
        $('#id_branches')
            .append('<option value="'+obj[i].id+'">'+obj[i].text+'</option>')
            .val(obj[i].id)
        ;
    });
 });
 $("#id_branches").select2();
});
```

Comment: please anyone there help me.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your code what is actually supposed to be happening here. Is there a chance you could create a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akgWg/3/) to demonstrate what you mean?